# Does Django automatically retrieve the parent object when a retrieved child object references that object?

Tags: django, django-models

In the Spring framework when an object A has a `ManyToOne` relation to object B:

```
public class objectA{

private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private objectB objectB;

}
```

Then that objectB is only fetched when the getter method for objectB is called somewhere i nthe code. In that case an extra SQL query is made to fetch objectB of that particular objectA instance. You can change that behaviour by changing the fetch strategy to EAGER, in that case objectB is also fetched during the initial query to fetch objectA.

My question is: What is the default fetch style that Django uses? Does Django always fetch any referenced parent objects or childobjects eagerly? Or does it differ per relation?

Thank you

Comment: Django ORM features are documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many to One in Django is defined by the [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) field

By default it fetches it lazily, meaning only when you are accessing that field.

The equivalent of `EAGER` is `.select_related('objectB')`. Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

---

select_related()

Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

The following examples illustrate the difference between plain lookups and select_related() lookups. Here’s standard lookup:

```
# Hits the database.
e = Entry.objects.get(id=5)

# Hits the database again to get the related Blog object.
b = e.blog
```

And here’s select_related lookup:

```
# Hits the database.
e = Entry.objects.select_related('blog').get(id=5)

# Doesn't hit the database, because e.blog has been prepopulated
# in the previous query.
b = e.blog
```